# How decentralized database works?

Tags: database, blockchain

How decentralized database works from technical point of view.

In general I understand that all the users have its own copy of data and somehow it gets in sync.

But this sync logic totally not clear do clients send http requests or what is happening ?

Any suggestion what to read or how to dive deeper into the topic is highly appreciated

UPDATE ===================

Thanks all for good replies, I want to make question a little bit more narrow 
It states that blockchain is dencetralized and owned by nobody so no public servers are in place

So what confuses me 
e.g. I have copy of DB another guy have the same database but slightly different how we can get synced in case we both don't have any public IPs?

In my mind if at least someone has a public IP it is already not completely decentralized

Comment: What kind of "database" you have in mind ? Question is to wide, please edit  it.

Comment: Sorry I can't make it more narrow. I am just interested in any database that is decentralized and question is about what to read to dive deeper in the subject so any narrow answer would be awesome

Comment: General comment how bitcoin database get sycned for example

Comment: Reading CAP theorem might help: https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-the-cap-theorem

Answer (score 3):

### Logic: State calculation from transactions

Decentralized systems / datastore works by *calculating the state*, where state is the actual data that you want to use from Database.

Say, you made modifications to the database by making 2 insert/update queries, the system actually takes these 2 queries and stores them as transactions in the database and these transactions will be synced across nodes(other machines in the network which make it decentralized). And that other node will be calculating state again based on the synced transactions and update it to the database.

---

### Let's try to understand this by an example:

Consider a **movie ticketing system**. The same theater will be listed in multiple vendor websites.

- Consider the movie theater to be a 100 seater (with 100 seats).
- And say there are 2 vendors. BookMyShow and TicketNew.

below is a list of transactions that happened on the network from time t1 to t9.

[image: Block sample]

- Transaction (T1) - At time(t1) someone bought 10 tickets on BookMyShow.
- Transaction (T2) - At time t2 someone else bought 3 more tickets on BookMyShow.

In BookMyShow database, the state will **initially be 100 unreserved tickets**.

After these 2 transactions(**T1 and T2**) state will be => **remaining 87 seats, booked 13** seats.
(So, the database of BookMyShow will have this information.)

Now the BookMyShow will add these 2 transactions **T1 and T2** into so called a **block** ( this is generally a list of transactions and some other parameters ), **B1**, and publish it to the network. The other vendor, TicketNew, will get this block **B1 synced** to his machine and will now know that these transactions happened. Now the TicketNew vendor's machine will start **calculating the state** of ticketing system by understanding the transactions.

- 100 Ticket initially.
- 10 Booked in T1 => 90 Seats remaining
- 3 Booked in T2 => 87 remaining

Update into TicketNew's database => remaining 87 seats, booked 13 seats

Similarly, T3, ...T6 transactions happen at times t3, ... t6 on TicketNew vendor's website. These transactions will be added to another block, B2 by TicketNew and pushed to the network. BookMyShow syncs the block B2 and updates state in its database that 26 tickets are booked now and 74 are free.

- 87 tickets before syncing block B2.
- 4 Booked in T3 => 83 Seats remaining
- 2 Booked in T4 => 81 remaining
- 6 Booked in T4 => 75 remaining
- 1 Booked in T4 => 74 remaining
- Update into BookMyShow database => remaining 74 seats, booked 26 seats

Comment: Hi thanks for such a detailed reply this is very interesting

Comment: The only thing I just don't understand is that e.g. I have a database on my local PC you have copy on your PC, for me totally not clear how we can get in sync in case we have no public IP addresses. So I mean how peer to peer works if no public addresses are in place

Comment: Browse for a protocol called IPFS. That should explain you most of it.
https://ipfs.io/ is their official website.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly Decentralised databases work is specific to its implementation.

[CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) is an example of a kind of distributed database. They use the [CouchDB Replication Protocol](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/replication/protocol.html) for synchronizing JSON documents between 2 peers over HTTP/1.1.

Couch DB basically uses [incremental replication](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/replication/intro.html#replication-intro) for syncing. You can read more about it.

[Hyperledger Fabric](https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/fabric) is a blockchain by IBM which uses Couch DB as the [ledger state database](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/ledger.html#chain) .

Answer (score 0):

Decentralized database like blockchain, whatever hyperledger or Bitcoin, is a kind of EventSource/CQRS implement, the ledger is append only EventSource, and sync to other node by consensus protocol, every node reply event log and get a state database for query, such as hyperledger uses couchdb or leveldb as state database.

Comment: >consensus protocol can you please dive more in this subject ?

Answer (score 0):

> How decentralized database works from technical point of view.

This is very broad and can take up an entire course to explain. A brief summery is, generally, a change will be a change in state made to one node. After this change in state, the node will broadcast the change to the rest of the nodes in the distributed system.

For blockchain, after a node adds a block to the chain, it will broadcast the new block to the 
rest of the nodes. These nodes will then come to a concensus that the new block is valid. If 
the other nodes do not come to a consensus, then they will keep working off the chain without the new block. That is a broad overview of how the system comes to a consensus.

> But this sync logic totally not clear do clients send http requests or
>   what is happening?

For Blockchain, the node that creates a new block will broadcast over http(s) the details of the new block to the other nodes. These nodes have to validate the block against the chain that they have on their system. When a node is working off different chains, this is called a fork. When the nodes come to a consensus, the fork that is deemed as the fork of truth is determined by the system.

Comment: How nodes can communicate over http ? if for this it is reburied to have public IP address at least ?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about synchronization. Just think about `git`: Someone changes code, commits his or her changes, pulls change of others that occured in the meanwhile and after that pushes the his or her final changes. Sure, sometimes you will have to merge stuff, but a good framework does it normally for you.

1. **Update**: *Commit your changes*
2. **Synchronize passively**: *Pull others changes*
3. **Synchronize actively**: *Push your changes*

If you are expirienced in JavaScript, then have a look at https://github.com/automerge/automerge. The documentation is very precise and explains the processes in a broder range. So it is not only intresting for web developers.